# waf - build works, custom build targets fail

Tags: c, build, waf

The waf command `waf build` shows compiler errors (if there are any) while `waf debug` or `waf release` does not and *always* fails, utilizing the following wscript file (or maybe the wscript file has some other shortcomings I am currently not aware of):

```
APPNAME = 'waftest'
VERSION = '0.0.1'
def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')
    ctx.define('VERSION', VERSION)
    ctx.define('GETTEXT_PACKAGE', APPNAME)

    ctx.check_cfg(atleast_pkgconfig_version='0.1.1')
    ctx.check_cfg(package='glib-2.0', uselib_store='GLIB', args=['--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=True)
    ctx.check_cfg(package='gobject-2.0', uselib_store='GOBJECT', args=['--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=True)
    ctx.check_cfg(package='gtk+-3.0', uselib_store='GTK3', args=['--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=True)
    ctx.check_cfg(package='libxml-2.0', uselib_store='XML', args=['--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=True)

    ctx.check_large_file(mandatory=False)
    ctx.check_endianness(mandatory=False)
    ctx.check_inline(mandatory=False)

    ctx.setenv('debug')
    ctx.env.CFLAGS = ['-g', '-Wall']
    ctx.define('DEBUG',1)

    ctx.setenv('release')
    ctx.env.CFLAGS = ['-O2', '-Wall']
    ctx.define('RELEASE',1)




def pre(ctx):
    print ('Building [[[' + ctx.variant + ']]] ...')


def post(ctx):
    print ('Building is complete.')

def build(ctx):
    ctx.add_pre_fun(pre)
    ctx.add_post_fun(post)

#   if not ctx.variant:
#       ctx.fatal('Do "waf debug" or "waf release"')

    exe = ctx.program(
        features = ['c', 'cprogram'],
        target = APPNAME+'.bin',
        source = ctx.path.ant_glob(['src/*.c']),
        includes = ['src/'],
        export_includes = ['src/'],
        uselib = 'GOBJECT GLIB GTK3 XML'
    )
#   for item in exe.includes:
#       print(item)



from waflib.Build import BuildContext

class release(BuildContext):
    cmd = 'release'
    variant = 'release' 

class debug(BuildContext):
    cmd = 'debug'
    variant = 'debug'
```

Error resulting from `waf debug` :

```
Build failed
 -> task in 'waftest.bin' failed (exit status -1): 
    {task 46697488: c qqq.c -> qqq.c.1.o}
[useless filepaths]
```

I had a look at the waf demos, read the [wafbook at section 6.2.2](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html#_custom_build_outputs) but those did not supply me with valuable information in order to fix this issue.

What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do at least the following:

```
def configure(ctx):
  ...
  ctx.setenv('debug')
  ctx.load('compiler_c')
  ...
```

Since the `cfg.setenv` function resets whole previous environment. If you want to save previous environment, you can do `cfg.setenv('debug', env=cfg.env.derive())`.

Also, you don't need to explicitly specify the `features = ['c', 'cprogram']`, since, it's redundant, when you call `bld.program(...)`.

P.S. Don't forget to reconfigure after modifying wscript file.